Cesium Viewer Crashes when clipping is enabled
I have an entity which has mouse over event enabled, and I am picking the entity using scene.pick as shown below.
const pickedObject = viewer.scene.pick(movement.endPosition);

This is throwing an error

[Cesium WebGL] Fragment shader compile log: ERROR: 0:424:
'clipPolygons' : no matching overloaded function found

This is happening only when I have enabled globe.clippingPolygons.
What could be the possible solution for this.
Here is a video of what's happening
https://youtu.be/RljMIWEXMvk
